# Get customer by Tax/VAT number

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, getmodel

I am looking to something similar to this one (thats works with email), But instead of get the customer by email, i want to get him by the  Tax/VAT number.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($customerEmail);
```

I found this example but  its doesn't work.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('taxvat',  $ss_5_last)->load();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935493/locate-customer-by-custom-attribute-in-magento) approach

```
$result = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
              ->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_‌​id')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('vat_id',$ss_5_last)->load()->getFirstItem();

if (is_object($result)) {
    /* Logic */
}
```

Keep in mind vat_id is not unique and the code below can load multiple customers without `->getFirstItem()`.

Comment: Tried it, dosent work

Comment: Well, it does't work is quite broad. What are you trying and what are you getting? The answer was accepted a while ago, are you sure this is not braking somewhere else?

Comment: Get empty results if i do "var_dump" on the object

Comment: That does not actually count as "it doesn't work". Are you sure you have at least one customer matching your filter criteria? How about the var you are passing to the model? Are you sure it is correctly formatted or even filed?